# Integrate json object with dropdown in Ionic 3 Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ion-select

I have been stuck trying to integrate a json response to a ion-option tag.
this is my html code:

```
<ion-item>
          <ion-label>Country</ion-label>
                  <ion-select formControlName="country">
                    <ion-option *ngFor="let value of values">{{value}}</ion-option>
                  </ion-select>
                </ion-item>
```

my values json object look like this:

```
values = {4: "Afghanistan", 8: "Albania", 10: "Antarctica", 12: "Algeria"};
```

This is defined in the related class of the above html file.

I get the following error:

> **ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object
>   Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables
>   such as Arrays.**

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is the format of JSON object not supported?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here demo link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fhpjje?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - iterating over json array inside a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162594/angular-2-iterating-over-json-array-inside-a-json-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values is an object it should be an array as follows,

```
values = [{"Afghanistan", "Albania","Antarctica", "Algeria"}];
```

you can convert the object to array as follows,

```js
var obj = {4: "Afghanistan", 8: "Albania", 10: "Antarctica", 12: "Algeria"}; 
var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return  obj[key];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response! but actually I'm receiving the above format through an api. I can't change it. Can you provide another solution?

Comment: Thanks it did the trick! but won't I be able to use the related ids?

Comment: you can still use ids

Comment: I actually upvoted it. no idea who downvoted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different from @Sajeetharan's answer. It's enough if your data is within an array, since JSON is directly not iterable over `ngFor`

```
values = {
            data: [
                {id: "4", value: "Afghanistan"},
                {id: "8", value: "Albania"},
                {id: "10", value: "Antarctica"},
                {id: "12", value: "Algeria"},
            ]
        };
```

and then you could do

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let val of values.data">{{val.id}}----{{val.value}}</ion-option>
```

Comment: any idea how I could use the ids in the json to this list?

Comment: Yes, Why not check updated answer, but slight modification in your response is required.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I actually used a function provided in one of the answers:
[Angular 2 - iterating over json array inside a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162594/angular-2-iterating-over-json-array-inside-a-json-object)
answer by: Ankit Singh

he has mentioned the use of a function:

```
generateArray(obj){
   return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]});
}
```

which converts my json object into an array!